# PDF of $Y \sim U [0, X]$ conditional on $X$ having exponential distribution with $\lambda= 1$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I need to find the probability density function to calculate $P(Y>1)$.

$Y\sim U [0, X]$

and we have that:

$X \sim\text{Exp}(1)$

So I know that the PDF of a uniform distribution equals:

\begin{equation}
PDF = 
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{b-a}\text{ if }x\in [a,b] \\
0\text{ otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

But I need to condition on $X$ being exponential, how should I continue?

Answer (score 2):

I have a different result.

As shown, Y-density is not necessary to calculate $P(Y>1)$

Being

$$f_{XY}(x,y)=\frac{e^{-x}}{x}\cdot\mathbb{1}_{(0;+\infty)}(x)\cdot\mathbb{1}_{(0;x]}(y) $$

We have

$$P(Y>1)=\int_1^{+\infty}\frac{e^{-x}}{x}\Bigg[\int_1^xdy\Bigg]dx=e^{-1}-\int_1^{+\infty}\frac{e^{-x}}{x}dx=e^{-1}-\Gamma(0;1)\approx0.3679-0.2194=0.1485$$

Answer (score 0):

You have the conditional probability density function of $Y$ given $X$, that is $f_{\small Y\mid X}(y\mid x)=\tfrac 1x\mathbf 1_{0\leqslant y\leqslant x}$ , since you were assured that $Y$ is uniformly distributed when *conditioned* over a given $X$.

You also have the marginal probability density function $X$, that is $f_{\small X}(x)=\mathrm e^{-x}\mathbf 1_{0\leqslant x}$ , since you were assured that $X$ is exponentially distributed with rate parameter of $1$.

This gives you the joint probability density function.$$f_{\small X,Y}(x,y)=\frac{\mathrm e^{-x}}{x}\mathbf 1_{0\leqslant y\leqslant x}$$

And the Law of Total Probability allows you to evaluate the marginal probability density function of $Y$ as:$$f_{\small Y}(y) = \mathbf 1_{0\leqslant y}\,\int_y^\infty \frac{\mathrm e^{-x}}{x}\,\mathrm d x$$

However, this does not have an elegant solution.   It is the definition for a generalised function, $\Gamma(0,y)$, known as the [Incomplete Gamma Function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/IncompleteGammaFunction.html) .$$f_{\small Y}(y)=\Gamma(0,y)\,\mathbf 1_{0\leqslant y}$$

Then $$\begin{align}\mathsf P(Y>1)&=\int_1^\infty \Gamma(0,y)\,\mathrm d y\\&= -\operatorname{E}_i(-1) + \mathrm e^{-1}\\&\approx 0.148496\end{align}$$

Where $\operatorname{E}_i(y)$ is another generalised function, the [Exponential Intergal function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ExponentialIntegral.html)

Comment: Thank you! I have one question left, I tried to derive the conditional expectation, but I am not quite sure how you derived that particular result. Could you show me please?

Comment: It was given to you that $Y\sim\mathcal U[0,X]$, which means that the conditional probability density function is $f_{\small Y\mid X}(y\mid x)= x^{-1}\,\mathbf 1_{y\in[0,x]}$.